# Array Animation C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Error na array de animation, vejam no video por favor que vão entender, na hora da troca de um objeto para outro ele fica totalmente apagado.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-WY1CRmGKM)

```
public Animation[] Animation1;
private int Selecao8;

   public void ProximaSelecao8()
{
   //Animation1 [Selecao8].SetActive (false);
   Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
   Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().enabled = false;
   Selecao8++;
   if (Selecao8 > Animation1.Length - 1) 
   {
      Selecao8 = 0;
   }
   //Animation1 [Selecao8].SetActive (true);
   Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
   Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().enabled = true;
}

   public void AnteriorSelecao8()
{
   //Animation1 [Selecao8].SetActive (false);
   Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
   Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().enabled = false;
   Selecao8--;
   if (Selecao8 < 0) 
   {
      Selecao8 = Animation1.Length -1;
   }
   //Animation1 [Selecao8].SetActive (true);
   Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
   Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().enabled = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. Sugiro focar sua dúvida e torná-la mais objetiva. Do jeito que está, não dá pra saber exatamente qual é a sua dificuldade. Por exemplo, *nesse código* atual o atributo `Animation1` *está comentado* e, portanto, não existe. O código deve estar dando erro de compilação justamente aí. Fora isso, o método `Play` deve ser invocado diretamente, pois ele *não é um array*. O array é o atributo `Animation1`, então vc deveria ter feito `Animation1[Selecao8].GetComponent<Animation>().Play();` muito provavelmente.

Comment: Só estou tentando fazer uma array de animation. Por Exemplo ativar e desativar, usando o lenght -1,1 nos onclicks só que não estou conseguindo se poder me ajudar ou consertar no que eu estou errando agradeceria muito.

Comment: Eu já te ajudei. Você leu o que eu escrevi? Sugiro que tente as alterações que eu sugeri e se, não funcionar, volte e edite a pergunta para deixar claro seu erro. Não leve a mal o comentário, mas este site não é um fórum e tampouco um "classificados" pra vc encontrar alguém pra fazer pra você. Se não fez ainda faça o [tour] e leia [ask].

Comment: kkkkkk tá bom... brincadeiras a parte, arrumei o erro que persistia. só que deu um problema, irei editar a pergunta com os feitos e o error.